An interface with side effects failed in some way not directly related to `mallctl*()` read/write processing
When I tried to dump rust in macOS 13.4 with M1 chip like this:
use jemalloc_ctl::{AsName, Access};
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[global_allocator]
static ALLOC: jemallocator::Jemalloc = jemallocator::Jemalloc;

const PROF_ACTIVE: &'static [u8] = b"prof.active\0";
const PROF_DUMP: &'static [u8] = b"prof.dump\0";
const PROFILE_OUTPUT: &'static [u8] = b"profile.out\0";

fn set_prof_active(active: bool) {
    let name = PROF_ACTIVE.name();
    name.write(active).expect("Should succeed to set prof");
}

fn dump_profile() {
    let name = PROF_DUMP.name();
    name.write(PROFILE_OUTPUT).expect("Should succeed to dump profile")
}

fn main() {
    set_prof_active(true);

    let mut buffers: Vec<HashMap<i32, i32>> = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..100 {
        buffers.push(HashMap::with_capacity(1024));
    }

    set_prof_active(false);
    dump_profile();
}

The output shows the following error:
thread 'main' panicked at src/main.rs:18:32:
Should succeed to dump profile: An interface with side effects failed in some way not directly related to `mallctl*()` read/write processing.
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

Does jemolloc not support macOS? Am I missing something? This is the Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "rust-learn"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
jemallocator = "0.3.2"
jemalloc-ctl = "0.3.2"

[dependencies.jemalloc-sys]
version = "0.3.2"
features = ["stats", "profiling", "unprefixed_malloc_on_supported_platforms"]

[profile.release]
debug = true

This is the rust version:
➜  rust-learn git:(rustflags) ✗ rustup -V
rustup 1.27.1 (54dd3d00f 2024-04-24)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.79.0 (129f3b996 2024-06-10)


MALLOC_CONF=prof:true need to be set when building jemalloc.
Before building the project, set it like the following:
export JEMALLOC_SYS_WITH_MALLOC_CONF="prof:true"

This will instruct jemalloc-sys to pass it to jemalloc.
If this still does not work, run cargo clean and rebuild the project.

I have tried to set the environment variable, but still did not fixed this issue. I am using visual studio code to run this code. I can use the code to read the environment variable: let api_key = env::var("MALLOC_CONF").expect("MALLOC_CONF must be set");

this setting works in remote linux machine.

@Dolphin You need to set it when compiling the project, not when running it. As I said, if it doesn't work, do cargo clean before.
